# Devextreme change color or apply style for components

Tags: devextreme

How can I change the color of DevExtreme TextBox?

Actually, how can I apply the css style for them, because also I need do apply `text-transform` to the component!

Demo

http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/editors-text_box-overview

**UPDATE**

I need to apply the css property to **specific components**, I'm using AngularJS!

I tried bellow with no success

```
 <div style="background-color : black" dx-text-box="textBox.simple"></div>
```

It would be nice if it provides a property from AngularJS code to apply css to the component!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Actually, how can I apply the css style for them, because also I need do apply text-transform to the component!

Hi! Here is Example:

```
.dx-textbox .dx-texteditor-input{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

> How can I change the color of DevExtreme TextBox?

For customize styles you can use [Theme Builder](http://js.devexpress.com/ThemeBuilder/)

**UPDATE**

This question has some solutions

**solution 1**:
you can set [attr property](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxTextBox/Configuration/?version=15_2#attr):

```
$scope.textBox = {
    simple: {
        value: "John Smith",
        attr: { style: "background-color: black" }
    }
}
```

**solution 2**:
It can be set by id or class:

*html:*

```
<div id="specificTextbox" dx-text-box="textBox.simple"></div>
```

*css:*

```
#specificTextbox .dx-texteditor-input{
    background-color : black;
}
```

Comment: The first example we apply to all components, I need to apply `text-transform: uppercase;` or any other `css property` to specific component. Sorry, I forgot to mention this detail, I need to apply css to specific component!